# Evaluation of deterministic functions

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

StoplightStatus

```
1  - Red
2  - Yellow
3  - Green
```

Since this is a deterministic function...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_StoplightStatusRed()
RETURNS TINYINT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    RETURN CAST(1 as TINYINT)
END
```

Is it safe to do...

```
SELECT
    [Status] = CASE StoplightStatusID WHEN dbo.udf_StoplightStatusRed() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM dbo.StoplightAudit
WHERE StopLightStatusID = dbo.udf_StoplightStatusRed()
```

The query itself doesn't make much sense, I know. I just want to be sure that if I do this, my function isn't being evaluated for each row.

I need to join to alot of other tables to get more information. Would it be better go get all of the audit IDs in a CTE first and join to that, or does it not matter since these functions are deterministic?

Comment: Check the execution plan. But SQL Server knows which functions are deterministic and I'm 100% confident that it optimizes away as a constant anything that doesn't depend on row values.

Answer (score 1):

Your function should be deterministic:

> Deterministic functions always return the same result any time they are called with a specific set of input values and given the same state of the database. Nondeterministic functions may return different results each time they are called with a specific set of input values even if the database state that they access remains the same.
>
> The Database Engine automatically analyzes the body of Transact-SQL functions and evaluates whether the function is deterministic. For example, if the function calls other functions that are non-deterministic, or if the function calls extended stored procedures, then the Database Engine marks the function as non-deterministic. For common language runtime (CLR) functions, the Database Engine relies on the author of the function to mark the function as deterministic or not using the SqlFunction custom attribute.